# Transform feedback without a framebuffer?

Tags: opengl, transform-feedback

I'm interested in using a vertex shader to process a buffer without producing any rendered output.  Here's the relevant snippet:

```
glUseProgram(program);

GLuint tfOutputBuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &tfOutputBuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, tfOutputBuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(double)*4*3, NULL, GL_STATIC_READ);

glEnable(GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD_EXT);

glBindBufferBase(GL_TRANSFORM_FEEDBACK_BUFFER, 0, tfOutputBuffer);
glBeginTransformFeedbackEXT(GL_TRIANGLES);

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, positionBuffer);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionAttribute);
glVertexAttribPointer(positionAttribute, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(double)*4, 0);

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, elementBuffer);

glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
```

This works fine up until the `glDrawElements()` call, which results in `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`.  And `glCheckFramebufferStatusEXT(GL_FRAMEBUFFER_EXT);` returns `GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED`.

I presume this is because my GL context does not have a default framebuffer, and I have not bound another FBO.  But, since I don't care about the rendered output and I've enabled `GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD_EXT`, I thought a framebuffer shouldn't be necessary.

**So, is there a way to use transform feedback without a framebuffer**, or do I need to generate and bind a framebuffer even though I don't care about its contents?

Comment: What did you expect `glCheckFramebufferStatus (...)` to return if you have no FBO bound and no default framebuffer? *GL_FRAMEBUFFER_UNDEFINED is returned if target is the default framebuffer, but the default framebuffer does not exist.*

Comment: I was just surprised to get a framebuffer-related error at all, since I was under the impression that `GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD_EXT` meant no framebuffer should be necessary.  So I got more information about the framebuffer situation, and included that information here in case it might help answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### This is actually perfectly valid behavior, as-per the specification.

> [OpenGL 4.4 Core Specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/doc/glspec44.core.pdf) - *9.4.4 Effects of Framebuffer Completeness on Framebuffer Operations*
>
> > A **`GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION`** error is generated by attempts to render to or read from a framebuffer which *is not framebuffer complete*. This error is generated ***regardless of whether fragments are actually read from or written to the framebuffer***. For example, it is generated when a rendering command is called and the framebuffer is incomplete, *even if **`GL_RASTERIZER_DISCARD`** is enabled*.

What you need to do to work around this is create an FBO with a 1 pixel color attachment and bind that. You ***must*** have a complete FBO bound or you get `GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION` and one of the rules for completeness is that at least 1 *complete* image is attached.

OpenGL 4.3 actually allows you to skirt around this issue by defining an FBO with no attachments of any sort (*see: [`GL_ARB_framebuffer_no_attachments`](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/framebuffer_no_attachments.txt)*). However, because you are using the EXT form of FBOs and Transform Feedback, I doubt you have a 4.3 implementation.

Comment: I see.  Thanks.  (Yes, unfortunately, at the moment I'm limited to OpenGL 2.1 + some extensions.)